# Magento call custom payment method via XMLConnect

Tags: magento-1.9, android, mage-xmlconnect

it has been developed Android native app by Magento XMLConnect so now problem is that default Magento payment method display in an android app but custom payment method is not display in checkout android app so Where I should change or Should I override XMLCoonect module files or add code in custom payment module? it is going blank in my mind Please give me hint so I can approach that way.